# If $f$ is continious ,then $G$ is connected ? True/false

Tags: general-topology

let $X$ be  a  compact  topological space  and let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be  function .The graph  of $f$  is the set  $G = \{(x,f(x)) : x \in  X \}  \subseteq    X \times  \mathbb{R}$.

Now my Question is that

If  $f$  is continious ,then $G$  is connected ? True/false

i thinks  it  will be true because continious image  of connected set is connected

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: Doesn't look like $X$ is assumed to be connected.

Comment: compact  implies  connected  @Randall

Comment: Huh?  $[0,1] \cup [3,4]$ is compact in the real line, but certainly not connected.

Comment: @Randall good logics.....this logic  did n't  came in my mind

Comment: You've stated that $X$ is compact, not connected. Is that a typo? There are certainly disconnected compact spaces.

Comment: Not  Typo  @dbx  my question is correct   but   my answer may be  wrong im doubtful;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and define $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$ by

> $f(x) = x$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=x-1$ if $x \in [2,3]$.

Then by **Pasting lemma** $f$ is continuous but has disconnected graph.

**Graph of $f$:**
[image]